# Represent $x_1=\frac{1-\sqrt{37}}{3}$ and $x_2=\frac{1+\sqrt{37}}{3}$ on a number line

Tags: real-numbers, number-comparison

In which case the numbers $x_1=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{37}}{3}$ and $x_2=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{37}}{3}$ are correctly represented on the number line?
[image]
I did the calculations with $\sqrt{36}=6$ and then we have $x_1\approx\dfrac{1-6}{3}=-\dfrac{5}{3}=-1\frac23$. So (Б) and (Г) are wrong answers. Now for $x_2\approx\dfrac{1+6}{3}=\dfrac{7}{3}=2\frac13$. The correct answer is В). I am not very proud of this solution so what else can we do? Thank you in advance!

Comment: That is the correct answer!  What more do you want?

Comment: What you did is completely correct: you took a very close value to $\;\sqrt{37}\;$ and you first ruled out two impossible answers, and then you just had to compare between the two other remaining possibilities...and you did it fine!

Comment: @DonAntonio, thank you for the response! But what happens if we cannot find a close value to the given root? That was my point.

Comment: You can always use approximate nice values. If you had, for example, $\;\sqrt{42}\;$ then you could always use that $\;6<\sqrt{42}<7\;$ . Things get a little messier, but it is possible to do it in a similar way.

Comment: @DonAntonio, what would I do if we were to have $x_1=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{42}}{3}$ and $x_2=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{42}}{3}$. Should I use $6$ or $7$ then?

Comment: @DonAntonio, I don't understand how I can use the inequality $6<\sqrt{42}<7$.

Comment: @Medi It all depends on what kind of geometric diagrams you're given. As in this case, it is expected the numbers are clearly drawn apart. If they were two give two options with very close points close to $\;1.5\;$ then it'd be too tough to decide which is the correct one.

Comment: Alternate solution: The two given expressions give two numbers that are equally far apart from $\frac13$. Three of the options depict numbers that are equally far apart from $0$ instead.

Comment: You don't need to approximate $\sqrt{37}$ is approximate $6$.  You can not that $6^2 = 36 < 37 < 49 = 7^2$ so $6 < \sqrt{37} < 7$.  So $\frac {1-7}3 < \frac {1-\sqrt {37}}3 < \frac {1-6}3$ so $-2 < x_1 < -\frac 53$.  So $- 2 < x_1 < -\frac 53 < -1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visual nature of the answer options means there very likely is no more rigorous way to solve this. Figure out which three *can't* be right, and keep the one remaining option as your answer. You did that very well, and you've completed the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response! But what happens if we cannot find a close value to the given root? That was my point when writing the question here... In the given problem $6$ is actually really close to the value of $\sqrt{37}\approx6,08$.

Comment: @Medi That was part of the design of the problem. You were meant to discover and exploit that approximation. At any rate, you can always tell which two consecutive integers a given square root is between, and make an educated guess as to which of the two it's closest to. For instance, $\sqrt{68}$ lies between $8$ and $9$, and is probably closer to $8$. In a problem like this, there is rarely any point in going further than that, as that's the limit of how exact we can be when picking points on a drawing of the number line.

Answer (score 3):

Symmetries  in the 4 options hint to an alternative way to solve the problem.  Given $x_1=\dfrac{1-a}{3}$ and $x_2=\dfrac{1+a}{3}$ , the center is $\frac {1}{2}(x_1+x_2)=\frac{1}{3}$ independent of $a$,(B) is the only choice.

Comment: Thank you for the response! How can I see that the two points should be symmetrical about $\dfrac13$?

Comment: Please see my update-:)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to approximate $\sqrt{37}\approx 6$ or to wonder .... "gee $\sqrt{42}$ is between $6$ and $7$ which should I use?"

Not that $36 < 37 < 49$ so $6 < \sqrt {37} < 7$.

So $-6 > -\sqrt{37} > -7$

$-5 = 1-6 > 1-\sqrt{37} > 1-7 = -6$

So $-\frac 53 >\frac {1-\sqrt{37}}3 > \frac {-6}3 = -2$.

So A) and B) is the best picture for that.

Likewise if the question was for $y_1 = \frac {1 - \sqrt {42}}3$ you'd do similar and not *have* pick choice over the other.

$36 < 42 < 49$ so.... well... the exact same thing happens.

$-\frac 53 >\frac { 1-\sqrt{42}}3 > -2$ and A) or B) are the best picture.

(BTW $-2 < y_1 < x_1 < -\frac 53$ where $y_1 =\frac {1-\sqrt{42}}3$ and $x_1 = \frac {1-\sqrt {37}}3$ in case you were curious or were ever asked to draw something like that.)